# Creating auto-shapes in excel based on cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, calendar

I'm trying to create (and maybe I shouldn't be using excel at all) a calendar with gantt chart style display in excel. I know there is software that is designed for gantt charts by themselves. That's not what I need.

I'm basically going to be responsible for providing my boss with a calendar like this: 
[image]

But I need to display start dates, end dates, and milestones within that. So what I have in mind is that I could have a function auto create a shape, and then auto populate the text within that shape (event name, etc).

If this is going to take some real programming, that's ok. I'm not worried about learning VBA, but I want to make sure that's the right path before I go down that road. If I should use some software other than Excel for this, I'm ok with that too.

Advice? Opinions?

Comment: That image is not a Gantt chart, it's a month view of a calendar. How would that calendar look with a few items of project task dates and milestones? Can you mock that up? TBH, your approach sounds totally wrong, especially if you first need to learn VBA.

Comment: Yes, correct. What I mean to say is I would overlay a gantt chart of sorts on a calendar that resembles the link.

I am ok with my approach being totally wrong, and open to suggestions on easier ways to try to accomplish this. Including not using Excel.

I'll try to post a mock-up later.

Comment: If cost isn't an issue you might do better using [Microsoft Project](https://products.office.com/en-gb/project/project-and-portfolio-management-software) which has built-in Gantt charts.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something Outlook calendar can do quite will.

However, what you are describing is doable. You will learn some VBA programming.

Some of it will look like this, to deposit a Gantt-like bar (without text yet) ...

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()
    Call InsertBar(0, 800)
End Sub
Sub InsertBar(LeftStart As Long, TotalWidth As Long)
Dim myWkSht As Worksheet
Dim myShp As Shape
Dim MaxWidth As Long, nBars As Long
Dim bDone As Boolean, iLoop As Long
Dim myStart() As Long, myWidth() As Long

If LeftStart < 0 Then Exit Sub
If TotalWidth <= 0 Then Exit Sub

Set myWkSht = Worksheets("Sheet2")
MaxWidth = myWkSht.Range("O1").Left
bDone = False
nBars = 1
ReDim myStart(1 To nBars)
ReDim myWidth(1 To nBars)
myStart(nBars) = LeftStart
myWidth(nBars) = TotalWidth
Do While Not bDone
    If myStart(nBars) + myWidth(nBars) < MaxWidth Then
        bDone = True
    Else
        nBars = nBars + 1
        ReDim Preserve myStart(1 To nBars)
        ReDim Preserve myWidth(1 To nBars)
        myStart(nBars) = 0
        myWidth(nBars - 1) = MaxWidth - myStart(nBars - 1)
        myWidth(nBars) = TotalWidth - myWidth(nBars - 1)
    End If
Loop
For iLoop = 1 To nBars
    With myWkSht
        Set myShp = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
            myStart(iLoop), .Range("A10").Offset((iLoop - 1) * 6, 0).Top, _
            myWidth(iLoop), .Range("A10").Offset((iLoop - 1) * 6, 0).Height)
    End With
    With myShp
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground2
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid

        .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground2
        .Line.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Line.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Line.Transparency = 0
    End With
Next iLoop
End Sub
```

My starting, rudimentary calendar mockup starts like this ...

[image]

... and looks like this after running the example code ...

[image]